# Box-shadow is not applied to element, how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have three bars of player status, i.e. health, experience, and mana. Health and Mana bars have a normal size and exp bar is minimized.

I apply box-shadow for each of them, styles are almost the same for all bars, however box shadow is not displayed for minimized bar. I tried to fix that and noticed that when I change spread radius to positive value, box shadow appears. If the spread radius is negative, box shadow is not displayed at all.

The code of PARENT element looks this way:

```
            <div className={styles.barContainer}>
              <Bar
                color={healthBar.color}
                height={healthBar.height}
                currentValue={healthCurrent}
                maxValue={healthMax}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={classNames(styles.barContainer, styles.barContainerSmall)}>
              <Bar
                size="small"
                color={expBar.color}
                height={expBar.height}
                currentValue={expCurrent}
                maxValue={expMax}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.barContainer}>
              <Bar color={manaBar.color} height={manaBar.height} currentValue={10} maxValue={10} />
            </div>
```

The Bar component looks this way:

```
      <div
        className={classNames(styles.bar, {
          [styles.smallBar]: size === 'small',
        })}
      >
        <div
          className={styles.barInner}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: color,
            width: `${Math.min(widthPercentage, 100)}%`,
          }}
        />
        {size !== 'small' && (
          <span className={styles.text} style={{ fontSize }}>
            <span className={styles.biggerNumber}>{currentValue}</span>/<span>{maxValue}</span>
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
```

And styles for the Bar:

```
    .bar {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
}

.smallBar {
  height: 5px;
}

.barInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition-property: width;
  animation: progressAnimation 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /** TODO: Change font color depending on contrast: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/ */
  color: #fff;

}

.text .biggerNumber {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Comment: When using a negative spread radius, you need to make sure your element is big enough. Also, what you're sharing is essentially pre-compiled Reactjs code that is likely irrelevant to the CSS issue at hand: share the generated HTML instead. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Terry this looks like an answer to this question. I tried to increase the size of the inner bar and once it's more than 8px the shadow appears! Thanks, it was something secret to me until now. You can submit it as an answer, I'll mark in as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#values), spread radius has the effect of growing or shrinking box shadows relative to the element's dimensions:

> Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to shrink.

Since you're using a spread radius of `-4px`, this means that the edges of the shadow will be inset 4px from the edges of the element. If your element has insufficient dimensions (i.e. width <8px or height <8px, as `4px * 2 = 8px`), the box shadow will not show since it will have a dimension of <0px in either axes.

Here is a proof-of-concept example, using the same `box-shadow` properties (but I increased the y offset to make it more obvious). Notice that the box shadow will only be rendered at elements of width >=9px:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#stage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 100px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 60px;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 20px;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width: 9px;"></div>
  
  <!-- No box shadow expected -->
  <div class="box" style="width: 8px;"></div>
</div>
```